# Export custom content type with fields

Tags: 8, entities, importing-exporting

I want to export a newly created content type which has bunch of fields to a new application installation. Also I need to export few views etc...

Exercise: I created a sandbox drupal 8 application. i have installed few modules to  my need and added a custom content type with few fields( taxanomy terms, file field, etc...). Added some content to test. I have finalized modules and content type.

Now In another environment, say dev, I installed drupal 8, used composer.json from sandbox and did composer update. this isntalled all the necessary modules in dev.

**How do I export the custom content types with fields and also views that I created in sandbox.**  I tried configuration synchronization. Imported the yaml files tar. I did not see any thing in sync tab and no content types.

Comment: Have you tried the config_installer module? https://www.drupal.org/project/config_installer

Comment: Also have you update the settings.php file to have the new site looking for the correct config folder where you saved all the yaml files?

Comment: Features: https://www.drupal.org/project/features

Comment: You wouldn't see anything in the sync tab of stuff you made in the sandbox when you want to export. You would just go to the Export tab and do "full export". There is no way to do selective exporting in Drupal without a module like Features, so it grabs all the relevant config related to what you are exporting. Barring that, drush and drupal console both have config export and config import commands too.